# Execute Process Task in SSIS to copy file from remote to local using WinSCP executable

Tags: ssis, winscp

I have a file StockExchangeData.txt in my remote server. I am trying to get it to my local drive `C:\User\KD\ExchangeData` using WinSCP (FTP).

In my SSIS, I have an "Execute Process Task". In its *Process* tab, I am using *Executable* as `C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe`. What shall I use in the arguments section to complete the download from remote server to my local drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To automate a download using WinSCP, use its [scripting interface](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting).

The simplest FTP download script specified on a [command-line](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline) is like:

```
/log=c:\path\to\log\winscp.log /command "open ftp://username:password@example.com/" "get /path/to/file.ext C:\User\KD\ExchangeData\" "exit"
```

Replace the `username`, `password` and `example.com` with the actual connection details. Use real paths.

For details see the [guide to automating file transfers from SFTP/FTP server using WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

You can also move the script commands to a separate script file to shorten the command-line parameters list.

Comment: Am I supposed to use the above command line in the argument section in the execute process task????

Comment: can you please explain the part - /log=c:\path\to\log\winscp.log. Are we doing a session logging here?

Comment: Yes, it's for session logging. It's essential as you have no other way to debug any issues.

Comment: One more question, what does the following do -                    V_FTP_COMMAND = C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe ;                                      exec ('[V_FTP_COMMAND]' , '/ console/ script=' || '[servername]' || '\StockExchangeData.txt',0)

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. I am starting to understand the solution now.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl -- I need small help. How can we download the all files available in folder with some specific name using same above logic.. for example I wish to download all the files having name like.. starting with name as ABC_

Comment: @vikrantrana Please post your question as an actual separate question. This is not a chat. This is Q&A site.

Comment: @ Martin Prikryl.. I have placed a question.. not able to connect to winscp server itself.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56650179/file-transfer-using-execute-process-task-in-ssis