# SFTP transfer using Execute Process Task and WinSCP in SSIS

Tags: ssis, sftp, winscp

I am having a `User_file.txt` file placed at WinSCP root folder USERDATA, which I am trying to download to the given location `C:\User\Local\`.

```
Executable- C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe
Arguments - /log=c:\path\to\log\winscp.log /command "open ftp://username:password@example.com/" "get /USERDATA/User_file.txt C:\User\Local\" "exit"
```

I am facing below error:

> No connection could be made the target machine actively refused it

Not sure what I am missing. I took reference from couple of related post on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use SFTP, but use FTP (`ftp://`) protocol in the [session URL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url).

Use `sftp://` instead:

```
... "open sftp://username:password@example.com/" ...
```

---

*WinSCP GUI can [generate a correct script/command-line template for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script).*